# Rails and ajax: confusion about callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm confused about ajax request in rails.

I'm submitting a form using ajax and everything was fine. Now I must handle callback, but...

Following some tutorials the hint is to add a

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js
end
```

to controler#create and then place in the views folder a "create.js.erb" with the response.

Other tutorials suggest to create a js file in the assets folder and handle the callback from the JS file.

What's the difference? And what's the right way?

Comment: What exactly is this callback supposed to do?

Comment: It depends... for example I need to clear the form input fields or I have to execute a controller action. I just need to know what's the differences between the two methods!

Answer (score 0):

Both are different ways for handling callback of Ajax request. I suggest you to use js.erb file to handle ajax callback because this file can recognize the both JS as well as Ruby code and execute.

For example,

in your controller,

```
def create
```

`...`

```
  if something
   @foo = true
  else
   @foo = false
  end
```

in your create.js.erb, it can be done like you want to show/hide some div based on the `@foo` value, you can write like,

```
<% if @foo %>
  // do something with JS code
<% else %>
 // do something else
<% end %>
```

While if you create a JS file in assets folder then you will not be able to write condition like above because it is a pure JS file and creating js.erb is an easy way to handle ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

They are two very different approaches. For example, assume that all you want to do is display a message confirming the user's submission. If you go down the create.js.erb route then that file might look something like

```
$('#message').text('<%= j @message %>')
```

The response to your ajax request is a bit of javascript that does the required changes to the ui. jQuery executes that javascript when it receives it and your javascript doesn't have any visibility into what the response might do.

The other approach would be for your controller just to render some data. This could either be some JSON describing the results of the submission, or a block of html. For example your controller might do

```
render json: {status: 'success', message: 'Thank you for your submission'}
```

The javascript making the xhr might look like

```
 $.ajax('/some_url', {dataType: 'json'}).done(function(data){
   //data is the json your controller sent
   $('#message').text data.message
 });
```

or if you were rendering html

```
 $.ajax('/some_url', {dataType: 'html'}).done(function(data){
   //data is the html your controller sent
   $('#message').html data
 });
```

So in this case it's your javascript that decides what to do with the returned data.

Personally I dislike the create.js.erb route - I find it makes my javascript harder to read: I can't tell from looking at my form submission code what can/may happen in this callback.

It's also much harder to test if controllers are producing a blob of something that needs to be executed in a different language and its much harder to test your javascript if there are places where it executes arbitrary code sent to it.

I much prefer it behaving like an api, returning structured data, that the client can act appropriately on (the client might not even be a browser all the time, it could be a mobile app).

Comment: No, they're completely different, although in general you can achieve the same things